# "applying in person" vs. "applying in-person"

Tags: hyphens

Does one write "applying in person" or "applying in-person" (with the hyphen)?

Example:

> When *applying in person* for this job, can one bring one's dog?

What I've found so far:

- https://www.ustraveldocs.com/cn/cn-niv-visarenew.asp uses a hyphen "Please note, if a parent or parents are *applying in-person* for a visa at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate General"
- https://www.cowley.edu/student_services/career/apply.html doesn't use a hyphen: "If *applying in person*, dress appropriately."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/in-person-vs-in-person-usage-are-they-interchangeable)

> In person means “in one’s bodily presence” as in ‘He met his boss in
> person a few weeks after the phone interview.’ In-person describes
> something done by (or with) a person who is physically present as in
> ‘She conducted several in-person interviews for the job.’
> ....
> Use in person as an adverb (modifying a verb, adjective, or adverb)
> and in-person as an adjective (modifying a noun).

Comment: yes, and many style guides will advise that when hyphenating the adjective form only do so before the noun, so _an in-person application_ but _an application in person_